# Cleaning Android FrameLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to write simple animation in Java, so I'm asking if any of You know how to clean completly framelayout.

Comment: Read `Ask Question` guidelines.

Comment: So did I. if I write, it mean that I can't find answer.

Comment: @user1433733 I think what darkcrow is saying, is that your question is poorly formatted in difficult to understand. You needed to invest more time into making your question legible and grammatically correct as much as possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reference your frame layout and then call `removeAllViews()` on that layout. This should clear the layout of all views.